# Transparent screenshot with PhantomJS in Selenium [Python]?

Tags: python, selenium, phantomjs, screenshot, transparent

When I take a screenshot in with PhantomJS as the webdriver in Selenium, all I get is a transparent background. Any clue why? It works with pages such as Google.com, but not kahoot.it, the one I want. It also works with everything else I need in Firefox, but not in PhantomJS.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities
import time

dcap = dict(DesiredCapabilities.PHANTOMJS)
dcap["phantomjs.page.settings.userAgent"] = ("Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/38.0.2125.122 Safari/537.36")
```

This is the code

```
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(desired_capabilities=dcap)
time.sleep(12)
driver.set_window_size(1024, 768)
driver.get('http://www.kahoot.it')

driver.save_screenshot('testing.png')
```

Any help would be much appreciated! :)

Comment: Not that familiar with selenium and PhantomJS.but, this seems relevant. `PhantomJS does not set the background color of the web page at all, it is left to the page to decide its background color. If the page does not set anything, then it remains transparent.`[PhantomJS FAQ](http://phantomjs.org/faq.html)

Comment: I cannot reproduce a transparent background on windows or linux with 1.9.7 and 1.9.8.

Comment: Wow, you were actually right. I'm using a Mac on Yosemite and I installed a VM with Windows 8 just to test it out. Everything worked flawlessly; the rest of the code, too. Don't really understand why, but thanks a lot! :)

Comment: This is useful Himal - you should consider submitting it as an answer

Comment: Hey, any luck with this issue? I'm getting the same and can't find any solution..

Comment: @ArtjomB. The solution for transparent backgrounds is to set by yourself the background-color atribute of body using javascript itself from webdriver.execute_script(). See answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your problem is about your website.

You typed it as http://www.kahoot.it but in the end, it does redirect to https site. So, your PhantomJS is getting errors from ssl version or ssl itself if where errors.

Modify your webdriver.PhantomJS() to that:
`driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(desired_capabilities=dcap, service_args=['--ignore-ssl-errors=true', '--ssl-protocol=any', '--web-security=false'])`
and all should run ok.

On the other hand, if you don't like transparent background set your own with:
`driver.execute_script('document.body.style.background = "black"')`.

With the first example you'll see only left frame blacked, that's because a top item has been set to white background. On the kahoot example you can't set it because that webpage has it's own javascript autochange script. You should remove it before attemp change it, otherwise your setting will be overrided soon or later.

Full code, ready to run:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#! -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import os
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities
import time

dcap = dict(DesiredCapabilities.PHANTOMJS)
dcap["phantomjs.page.settings.userAgent"] = ("Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/38.0.2125.122 Safari/537.36")


driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(desired_capabilities=dcap, service_args=['--ignore-ssl-errors=true', '--ssl-protocol=any', '--web-security=false'])
driver.set_window_size(1024, 768)
driver.get('http://www.httpbin.org')
time.sleep(2)
driver.execute_script('document.getElementsByClassName("mp")[0].style.background = "green"')
#driver.execute_script('document.body.style.background = "black"')
driver.save_screenshot('testing1.png')

driver.get('http://www.kahoot.it')
time.sleep(2)
driver.execute_script("var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]; body.setAttribute('background-color', 'white')")
driver.execute_script('document.body.style.background = "black"')
driver.save_screenshot('testing2.png')
```

As a suggestion for other transparent issues if you don't wanna look for DOM items, just convert your png to jpg using Image class for python and every transparent pixel would be set to white.